# Intel VT-x not working on Lenovo z510

Tags: virtualization, vt-x

I wanted use my Lenovo z510 to test the new android lollipop using HAXM, but while installing it said that I have no VT-x technology. The product page says that my processor(intel pentium 3550m @ 2.30 GHz) supports VT-x and I have virtualization enabled in BIOS. I have been searching for a soultion in the past 3 hours, but no one had the same problem.

Comment: Are you sure VT-X (not VT-d) is enabled in BIOS? And if Hyper-V is enabled then disable it. What OS is your computer? If it's Win7 or below then download the Microsoft HAV Detection tool for more info.

Comment: It says Vanderpool is enabled, which I read is an earlier name for virtualization. Hyper-V is disabled, and my OS is an OEM Windows 8.1.

Comment: OK run this tool and check if virtualisation is enabled https://www.grc.com/securable.htm

Comment: Also some laptops require you to shut down and power off the laptop after enabling VT-x in the BIOS, and **removing the power cable and battery** for 30 seconds.